# SHA on apache directory studio

Tags: apache-ds

I am using Apache Directory Studio for browsing and user administration of openLDAP
(working on mac, so no better options)
when i set-up a new password for users with SHA-1 the new password appears as

{sha}e3NoYX1NMW80ZzYvYkFseGZIcnExcGdmNWFGQUZTNU09

but our server runs synchronization with google mail server
and it only recognize the password when they are

{SHA}e3NoYX1NMW80ZzYvYkFseGZIcnExcGdmNWFGQUZTNU09

since password is of course case sensitve - the user can not log into his mail account

is there a way to tell apache-DS to create the {sha} prefix in capital letters {SHA} ?

Thanks

Danny